# Keep reading Command-line until you get the word END

Tags: beginner, go, io

I have to write a code which takes (integers) numbers from Command-line and keeps reading the terminal until it gets a word `END`

So I wrote the following; I feel its really bad. Is there any way I can improve below code

I updated my code from [previously](https://play.golang.org/p/FfIuuZ26QtX) to below

```
func main() {
    buf := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    lines, err := buf.ReadBytes('\n')

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf(" %q \n", string(lines))
    line := strings.Replace(string(lines), "\n", "", -1)

    numbers := strings.Split(line, " ")
    fmt.Printf("numbers %q ", numbers)
    var sum int64
    for _, num := range numbers {
        num, err := strconv.ParseInt(num, 10, 0)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            break
        }
        sum += num
    }
    fmt.Println("Sum of all numbers :", sum)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> takes (integers) numbers from Command-line and keeps reading the
>   terminal until it gets a word END.

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    sum := int64(0)
    s := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    s.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    for s.Scan() {
        word := s.Text()
        num, err := strconv.ParseInt(word, 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            if strings.ToUpper(word) == "END" {
                break
            }
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
            continue
        }
        sum += num
    }
    if err := s.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Sum of all numbers:", sum)
}
```

Terminal:

```
12 24 
36 
6
6
  END
Sum of all numbers: 84
```